# 4 Column Footer Not Stacking for Mobile

Tags: html, css, footer

So basically I've got this 4 column footer and it's perfect, but rather than stacking for mobile, it just gets smashed.
I just want each category to stack once it swaps to mobile view, or just shrink responsively across all sizes.
I've tried setting widths but no luck.  Any help or tips would be appreciated!

```css
footer .clear {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}

footer {
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 58px 0 0;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

footer p,
footer ul,
footer a,
footer .btn {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-transform: none;
}

footer li {
  font-size: .875em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

footer .btn {
  background: #4497c4;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
  -moz-border-radius: 5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff!important;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 15px 6px 15px;
  border: solid #25658a 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
}

footer .content {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  footer .content {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
}

footer .last {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 485px) {
  footer .last {
    clear: both;
  }
}

#emailsignup {
  float: left;
  width: 330px;
}

#emailsignup .footer-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 155px;
  height: 41px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-proxibid.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#emailsignup a,
#helpfullinks a,
#social a,
#poweredby a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#emailsignup p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px 0px 16px;
}

#helpfullinks {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 825px) {
  #helpfullinks {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#helpfullinks div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 45px;
  width: 20%;
}

#helpfullinks div a {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#helpfullinks p.category {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin: 0 0 14px;
}

#helpfullinks p.category a {
  color: #FFF;
}

#helpfullinks ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 14px 0 0 0;
}

#helpfullinks li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#poweredby {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 115px auto 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #poweredby {
    margin: 26px auto 0;
  }
}

#poweredby p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#poweredby ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

#poweredby li {
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 495px) {
  #poweredby li {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#poweredby .footer-divvy {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-divvy.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#poweredby .footer-finest {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-thefinest.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#poweredby .footer-apn {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-apn.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#social {
  margin: 60px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #social {
    margin: 26px auto;
  }
}

#social ul {
  margin: 0px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

#social ul.social,
#social ul.contact {
  display: inline-block;
}

#social li {
  margin: 0 17px 0 0;
  float: left;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 495px) {
  #social li {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#social li a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

iframe {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#footerSealiFrame {
  border: medium none;
  height: 175px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #footerSealiFrame {
    height: 285px;
  }
  #footerSeals>img,
  #footerSeals>embed,
  #footerSeals>object,
  #footerSeals>a {
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin: 0 6px 10px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="helpfullinks">
      <div>
        <p class="category">About</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">AdaptaPASS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Affiliates</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Campus Representatives</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="category">Products</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">All-Access Course Bundles</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CRAM Courses</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Audio Lectures</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TestBank Software</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Digital Flashcards</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Exam Stress Relief</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="category">Resources</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Free Assessment</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Start a Free Trial</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Requirements by State</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="last">
        <p class="category">Support</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">(800) 824 2811</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Use the chat feature below to reach one of our support specialists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login to AdaptaPASS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login to myYaeger Student Portal</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="poweredby">
      <ul>
        <li class="last"><img src="include/images/footerlogo.png"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="social">
      <ul class="social">
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a target="_blank" href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <ul class="contact">
        <li class="last">&copy;2017 Yaegar CPA Review, All Rights Reserved</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, what you need to do is kill the `floats` and reset the `width` at the appropriate viewport widths, for example:

```
#helpfullinks div { /* for the sake of demonstration */
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
footer .clear {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}

footer {
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 58px 0 0;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

footer p,
footer ul,
footer a,
footer .btn {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-transform: none;
}

footer li {
  font-size: .875em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

footer .btn {
  background: #4497c4;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
  -moz-border-radius: 5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff!important;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 15px 6px 15px;
  border: solid #25658a 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
}

footer .content {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  footer .content {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
}

footer .last {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 485px) {
  footer .last {
    clear: both;
  }
}

#emailsignup {
  float: left;
  width: 330px;
}

#emailsignup .footer-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 155px;
  height: 41px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-proxibid.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#emailsignup a,
#helpfullinks a,
#social a,
#poweredby a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#emailsignup p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px 0px 16px;
}

#helpfullinks {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 825px) {
  #helpfullinks {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#helpfullinks div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 45px;
  width: 20%;
}

#helpfullinks div a {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#helpfullinks p.category {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin: 0 0 14px;
}

#helpfullinks p.category a {
  color: #FFF;
}

#helpfullinks ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 14px 0 0 0;
}

#helpfullinks li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#poweredby {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 115px auto 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #poweredby {
    margin: 26px auto 0;
  }
}

#poweredby p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#poweredby ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

#poweredby li {
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 495px) {
  #poweredby li {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#poweredby .footer-divvy {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-divvy.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#poweredby .footer-finest {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-thefinest.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#poweredby .footer-apn {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-apn.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#social {
  margin: 60px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #social {
    margin: 26px auto;
  }
}

#social ul {
  margin: 0px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

#social ul.social,
#social ul.contact {
  display: inline-block;
}

#social li {
  margin: 0 17px 0 0;
  float: left;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 495px) {
  #social li {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#social li a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

iframe {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#footerSealiFrame {
  border: medium none;
  height: 175px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #footerSealiFrame {
    height: 285px;
  }
  #footerSeals>img,
  #footerSeals>embed,
  #footerSeals>object,
  #footerSeals>a {
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin: 0 6px 10px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
  }
}


/* Additional */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #helpfullinks div {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5a5a5a;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="helpfullinks">
      <div>
        <p class="category">About</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">AdaptaPASS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Affiliates</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Campus Representatives</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="category">Products</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">All-Access Course Bundles</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CRAM Courses</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Audio Lectures</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TestBank Software</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Digital Flashcards</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Exam Stress Relief</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="category">Resources</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Free Assessment</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Start a Free Trial</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Requirements by State</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="last">
        <p class="category">Support</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">(800) 824 2811</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Use the chat feature below to reach one of our support specialists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login to AdaptaPASS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login to myYaeger Student Portal</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="poweredby">
      <ul>
        <li class="last"><img src="include/images/footerlogo.png"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="social">
      <ul class="social">
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a target="_blank" href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <ul class="contact">
        <li class="last">&copy;2017 Yaegar CPA Review, All Rights Reserved</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**Bonus**

Because it's *Friday* and I'm feeling particularly generous, here's a `flex-box` method:

```
#helpfullinks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

```css
footer .clear {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}

footer {
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 58px 0 0;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

footer p,
footer ul,
footer a,
footer .btn {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-transform: none;
}

footer li {
  font-size: .875em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

footer .btn {
  background: #4497c4;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
  -moz-border-radius: 5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff!important;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 15px 6px 15px;
  border: solid #25658a 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
}

footer .content {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  footer .content {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
}

footer .last {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 485px) {
  footer .last {
    clear: both;
  }
}

#emailsignup {
  float: left;
  width: 330px;
}

#emailsignup .footer-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 155px;
  height: 41px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-proxibid.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#emailsignup a,
#helpfullinks a,
#social a,
#poweredby a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#emailsignup p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px 0px 16px;
}

#helpfullinks {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 825px) {
  #helpfullinks {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#helpfullinks div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 45px;
  width: 20%;
}

#helpfullinks div a {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#helpfullinks p.category {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin: 0 0 14px;
}

#helpfullinks p.category a {
  color: #FFF;
}

#helpfullinks ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 14px 0 0 0;
}

#helpfullinks li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#poweredby {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 115px auto 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #poweredby {
    margin: 26px auto 0;
  }
}

#poweredby p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#poweredby ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

#poweredby li {
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 495px) {
  #poweredby li {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#poweredby .footer-divvy {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-divvy.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#poweredby .footer-finest {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-thefinest.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#poweredby .footer-apn {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-apn.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#social {
  margin: 60px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #social {
    margin: 26px auto;
  }
}

#social ul {
  margin: 0px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

#social ul.social,
#social ul.contact {
  display: inline-block;
}

#social li {
  margin: 0 17px 0 0;
  float: left;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 495px) {
  #social li {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#social li a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

iframe {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#footerSealiFrame {
  border: medium none;
  height: 175px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #footerSealiFrame {
    height: 285px;
  }
  #footerSeals>img,
  #footerSeals>embed,
  #footerSeals>object,
  #footerSeals>a {
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin: 0 6px 10px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
  }
}


/* Bonus (let's get Flexy) */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #helpfullinks {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-flow: wrap;
  }
  #helpfullinks div {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5a5a5a;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="helpfullinks">
      <div>
        <p class="category">About</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">AdaptaPASS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Affiliates</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Campus Representatives</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="category">Products</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">All-Access Course Bundles</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CRAM Courses</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Audio Lectures</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TestBank Software</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Digital Flashcards</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Exam Stress Relief</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="category">Resources</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Free Assessment</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Start a Free Trial</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Requirements by State</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="last">
        <p class="category">Support</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">(800) 824 2811</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Use the chat feature below to reach one of our support specialists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login to AdaptaPASS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login to myYaeger Student Portal</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="poweredby">
      <ul>
        <li class="last"><img src="include/images/footerlogo.png"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="social">
      <ul class="social">
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a target="_blank" href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <ul class="contact">
        <li class="last">&copy;2017 Yaegar CPA Review, All Rights Reserved</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: for some reason this makes the whole footer only 600px at ALL sizes, so even on desktop it shows a 600px width footer.
When I remove the set 600px, it just makes it look crazy.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, I only inlined that style for the sake of demonstration  - you should take it out hahaha. Apologies for the confusion. (Essentially to demonstrate *how* it would look at, say, `600px`, I could've gone with `500px`, or `450px`, these styles should only be applied at whatever viewport you need these columns to ocuupy the full-width. So insert them into the right `@media` query breakpoint)

Comment: sorry if I'm coming off as annoying, I'm still learning, but after changing that, even if I set the width at default size to 100%, it's still giving me a stacked option, rather than being normal at computer resolution. :/ Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't stress. Are you placing those styles under a media query like `@media screen and (max-width: 768px)`?

Comment: I placed the 100% width above all the media queries so that it would be the original.

Comment: Looks like there was a duplication in code - I've update the answer to remove it. Now the new styles are only in a media query breakpoint (`600px`) - you might want to mover this though to `768px` or wherever else you need it.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You have used pixels instead of percentage for `margin-right`. So if we convert the remaining space into percentage we will get approximately 6.66% per each div. So we can achieve the required layout.

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}

footer {
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 58px 0 0;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

footer p,
footer ul,
footer a,
footer .btn {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-transform: none;
}

footer li {
  font-size: .875em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

footer .btn {
  background: #4497c4;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4497c4, #2d6a8e);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
  -moz-border-radius: 5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff!important;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 15px 6px 15px;
  border: solid #25658a 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;
}

footer .content {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  footer .content {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
}

footer .last {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 485px) {
  footer .last {}
}

#emailsignup {
  float: left;
  width: 330px;
}

#emailsignup .footer-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 155px;
  height: 41px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-proxibid.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#emailsignup a,
#helpfullinks a,
#social a,
#poweredby a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#emailsignup p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px 0px 16px;
}

#helpfullinks {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 825px) {
  #helpfullinks {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#helpfullinks div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6.66%;
  width: 20%;
}

#helpfullinks div a {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#helpfullinks p.category {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin: 0 0 14px;
}

#helpfullinks p.category a {
  color: #FFF;
}

#helpfullinks ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 14px 0 0 0;
}

#helpfullinks li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#poweredby {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 115px auto 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #poweredby {
    margin: 26px auto 0;
  }
}

#poweredby p {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#poweredby ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

#poweredby li {
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 495px) {
  #poweredby li {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#poweredby .footer-divvy {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-divvy.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#poweredby .footer-finest {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-thefinest.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#poweredby .footer-apn {
  display: block;
  width: 77px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("https://www.proxibid.com/images/footer-logo-apn.png") top left no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#social {
  margin: 60px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #social {
    margin: 26px auto;
  }
}

#social ul {
  margin: 0px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

#social ul.social,
#social ul.contact {
  display: inline-block;
}

#social li {
  margin: 0 17px 0 0;
  float: left;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 495px) {
  #social li {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
  }
}

#social li a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

iframe {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#footerSealiFrame {
  border: medium none;
  height: 175px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #footerSealiFrame {
    height: 285px;
  }
  #footerSeals>img,
  #footerSeals>embed,
  #footerSeals>object,
  #footerSeals>a {
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin: 0 6px 10px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="helpfullinks">
      <div>
        <p class="category">About</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">AdaptaPASS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Affiliates</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Campus Representatives</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="category">Products</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">All-Access Course Bundles</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CRAM Courses</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Audio Lectures</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TestBank Software</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Digital Flashcards</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Exam Stress Relief</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="category">Resources</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Free Assessment</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Start a Free Trial</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Requirements by State</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="last">
        <p class="category">Support</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">(800) 824 2811</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Use the chat feature below to reach one of our support specialists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login to AdaptaPASS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login to myYaeger Student Portal</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="poweredby">
      <ul>
        <li class="last"><img src="include/images/footerlogo.png"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="social">
      <ul class="social">
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a target="_blank" href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <ul class="contact">
        <li class="last">&copy;2017 Yaegar CPA Review, All Rights Reserved</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```